# Read xml string into dataset

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-web-api

I'm getting xml content from a web api. The xml content is a datatable which was converted to xml in the controller and returned as a string.

I try to read it back in a dataset as follows:

```
var results = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
byte[] xmlBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(results);

using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(xmlBytes))
{
    ds.ReadXml(ms);
    dt = ds.Tables[0];
}
```

However is dataset is empty.

The web api controller action does the following:

```
string xml = string.Empty;

using (DataTable dt = GetResultsAsDataTable())
{
    if (dt != null)
    {
        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            dt.WriteXml(sw, true);
            xml = sw.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

The string looks like this:

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"><DocumentElement>
    <tablename>
        <id>734</id>
        <name>734</name>
    </tablename>
</DocumentElement></string>
```

Is it normal that the xml string looks like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely not.

You should fix `results` first:

```
results = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(results);
```

Then, `results` will look like this:

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"><DocumentElement>
    <tablename>
        <id>734</id>
        <name>734</name>
    </tablename>
</DocumentElement></string>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you shall make your controller action return a datatable object, then the Web API framework will convert it to XML automatically by default, but the XML maybe hard to read.
here is the code I tried,[C# Code](http://pastebin.com/ekbWAsFc),[returned XML](http://pastebin.com/vxB4z5xR)